# Find where a log was triggered

Tags: java, android, logging

So I'm reviewing a friends's android project and I see his logs but I cant find where some of his logs are getting triggered in order to figure the flow. Is there any way to find from which class a particular log comes?

Comment: The usual trick is to log a fake exception (for the stack): `Logger.log("some message", new RuntimeException())` or something like that

Comment: since it is a log it should have a message. try to search in "solution" for every occurrence of the log text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If project is not configured to show where logs were triggered you can try to use `ctrl + shift + f` shortkey (shift + cmd + f for Mac OS) and try to search for log's message. If logs are custom you should find them that way.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the logger you are using and how you configure it.
The log itself is nothing more than a text file. You cannot alter this afterwards.

If you cannot configure your logger to show classes. You could log the current class (or even your current method) in your log statements.